# "Waiting for network configuration" upon boot

Tags: ubuntu, networking

When I boot, I get the error message `waiting for network configuration`, then `waiting an additional 60 seconds for network configuration`.

I had edited `/etc/network/interfaces` file before the above message, so as to surf through a friend's laptop using Ethernet cable; then, after restoring the file, I still get the same message. I have searched in the internet but I didn't find anything helpful.

The content of `/etc/network/interfaces` is:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configurations seem fine. Check if you saved the file after editing, if not

`sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces` if you are using nano

`sudo vim /etc/network/interfaces` if you use vim
the remove whatever is there and replace with the following
 `auto lo iface lo inet loopback`

reboot now, and you should be ok :)

Answer (score 3):

You are missing eth0 section, try **adding** the following

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Then reboot.

Comment: Linux is different from Windows. Just do `ifup eth0` after editing, maybe a `ifdown eth0` before.